# How to provision site assets with PnPProvisioningTemplate

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, pnp, team-sites, pnp-provisioning

I am trying to include company-wide images in my provisioning of Team sites in Sharepoint Online. I would use an organization asset library, but my Sharepoint topography is based on Hub sites with no site being a part of a single site collection. I am not sure if including images in a provisioning template is possible, but here is the current command I am running to try and achieve this.

```
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -Path SiteTemplate.xml -ResourceFolder '.\resources' -ClearNavigation
```

My file structure looks as follows:

```
root (folder)
    SiteTemplate.xml
    SiteProvisioningScript.ps1
    resources (folder)
        MyImage1.png
        MyImage2.png
```

My Get-PnPProvisioningTemplate correctly adds the Company Assets folder that I have included in the template team site. The Company Assets folder on the template site also has the images MyImage1.png and MyImage2.png inside of it.

Any help or guidance you can give me is greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution.

I Used:

```
Add-PnPFileToProvisioningTemplate -Path SiteTemplate.xml -Source '.\resources\MyImage1.png' -Folder 'CompanyAssets'
```

Which inserted the MyImage1.png into the CompanyAssets folder in the newly provisioned Team site.